# How to define multiple words prepending figure/table titles in Markdown?

Tags: markdown, pandoc, cross-reference

For me it is important that I can make references from within the main body of a text to figures and tables that are not part of the main document. For example, can I define "Figure xx", where 'xx' is the number of the figure, as one prefix for all figures inside the main document and "Suppl.Figure xx" as a second prefix for figures that will not show up in the main part of a text?

I am writing a research paper in Markdown and use `Pandoc` as a converter between multiple file formats to cater to the preferences of different project partners. Moreover, I have downloaded `pandoc-crossref` (https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref), which is nice for general referencing needs, but I have not yet found a way around this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not possible with Pandoc.  Internal references to figures are [discussed](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/813) and will probably make it into Pandoc at some later time.  For now, I suggest to include LaTeX snippets instead (assuming PDF is the final format).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. That saved me some time of fruitless research. I'll keep this question open for now; hope you won't mind.

Comment: @mattw I don't mind at all, glad I could help.  If things change, one can always change the accepted answer if a better one comes up later.  Anyway, have fun with pandoc, and try it's org-mode reader sometime 